# how to remove origin: file:// while doing rest call to server, via android app (created using phonegap/cordova)?

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap-plugins, phonegap

I am making an ajax call to server like below:

```
$.ajax({
          type : "POST",
          dataType : "json",
          url : url+ "/oms/rest/XYZ/anon/uvw/grantAbc",
          data : {
            "username" : username,
            "password" : password
          },
```

But on server side it's failing because **origin:file://** getting sent with rest call.
[image: requesr header]

Comment: Is there any plugin which can do my help?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the origin from file:// because you literally have no origin. The issue is that your REST back-end does not allow file:// as origin. You need to change that in your back-end.